# the importance of buffersize

Tags: asp.net, buffer, buffering

While streaming big files (more than 150mb) with ASP.NET, to what should the buffersize be set? I use 16kb as default.

Does making the buffersize bigger (for example 320kb) increase performance and decrease server load?

Answer (score 0):

The smaller the buffer the slower the transfer. The larger the buffer the more memory you will potentially use.

Found a similar posting [When handling large file transfers in ASP.NET what precautions should you take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276088/when-handling-large-file-transfers-in-asp-net-what-precautions-should-you-take) The MS Site recommends 100000 bytes but if your site can handle the higher buffer then use it.